# How do you create a program that will remove from the 2nd character to the space?

Tags: java, string, replace, indexof

I am trying to find a way to create a program where users input their full name(first last) and that can remove multiple characters from the second character to another specific character which is the space with StringBuilder. Meaning it will print out the first initial and the entire last name.

Example:

Input:
**Barrack Obama**

Output:
**BObama**

Comment: Sorry about the unclear part, I want the user to type on their full name, and then create a program that will remove from the 2nd character to the space. Like school emails: Barrack Obama = BObama or Donald Trump = DTrump.

Comment: @DonghunCho1234 I already answered your question and provided a sample code that delete the second character until space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will delete from the second character until the first space detected. For example from `Dong Cho` to `DCho`

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName;

    System.out.println("Enter username"); 
    userName = scanner.nextLine();   
    
    int spaceIndex = userName.indexOf(" ")+1;
    String firstPartOfString = userName.substring(0, 1);
    String lastPartOfString = userName.substring(spaceIndex, userName.length());
    userName = firstPartOfString +lastPartOfString;
    
    System.out.println(userName);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what if it was a user's input?

Comment: User's Input: Donghun Cho      Output: Dcho

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood the question but I already updated the correct answer, you may have a look at it. It deletes from the second character until the space

Comment: Is there any way to create this project without StringBuilder and only substring and indexOf, etc?

Comment: Yes I already updated my answer to only use `substring` and `indexof`

Answer (score 2):

You can either use two `substring`s, which will create two intermediate `String` objects, or you can use a `StringBuilder` object as follows:

```
String input = "Hello everyone, I'm Cho.";
String output = new StringBuilder(input).delete(5, 14).toString(); // "Hello, I'm Cho."
```

Comment: If this had a user's input, is there a way to remove characters only from 2nd character to the space?